# How to read cookie from another cross domain url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, cookies

I have a cross domain url in which if I access directly, I can see cookies(from Resources->Cookies in chrome browser).

I have created a separate HTML file in which whenever the HTML file page loads, I need to get the cookie from that url.

Is it possible through javascript?

Comment: I doubt it - it defeats the object of sandboxing and "domain" security.  Resources >Cookies works because you the user on that machine and access is assumed - for want of a better word.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Answer (score 5):

You can not read the cookies from cross domain url, unless the website has explicitly allowed it. (that is very rare)

Generally **You can not do it.**